# Place Dynamically Generated Objects in an Array (or Collection)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arrays, variables, collections

I created a custom class for a custom object. I instantiate like so:

```
Dim class_info as New class_level
```

Then I use a LINQ-to-Entities query to pull some information:

```
Dim get_config = From p in dbContext.Configs _
    Where p.Type = "classdate" _
    Select p
```

Then I have a For..Each loop that I want to create an instance of the object from this information like so:

```
    For Each row In get_config
        Dim the_row = row
        class_info.class_level = the_row.Description
        class_info.dateo = the_row.dateValue
        class_info.timeo = the_row.timeValue
        class_info.datec = the_row.dateValue
        class_info.timec = the_row.timeValue
        class_info.query = "q" + the_row.Description
    Next
```

Now, I have two problems. First, right now this is just overwriting the same object properties, again, and again. I need to somehow dynamically name the object. Then, I need to place these objects in an array so I can iterate through them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really should do is to project your query into the type directly:

```
Dim class_infos = From p in dbContext.Configs _
                  Where p.Type = "classdate" _
                  Select New class_level With {
                     .Prop = p.Prop
                     ' other properties here
                  }
```

Then you will end up with an `IEnumerable` of `class_level`, which I think is what you want?

You should consider naming things a bit better as it's hard to understand what you are working with here.

Comment: +1 on using naming guidelines.  Check this site for naming guidelines:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx  and this for other best practices:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h63fsef3.aspx

Comment: When I add multiple properties I get the problem that intellisense thinks I am still working with the LINQ-to-Entities code (p.Prop) is there a way to tell it I'm not?

Comment: You are indeed working with LINQ-2-SQL. If you call `ToList()`, `AsEnumerable()` or `ToArray()` on your result, the LINQ-2-SQL query will be evaluated and executed and you will switch LINQ-provider to the in-memory provider.